Oracle Instant Client download zips do not have the mesg folder
I am trying to install sqlplus without the rest of the oracle client onto a laptop with windows 11. I installed it from the instant client zip but when I run it I get the message SP2-0667: Message file sp1.msb not found
I have already set the ORACLE_HOME system variable and added the folders to the beginning of PATH. The problem is that the mesg folder does not exist in ANY of the instant client zips. I downloaded them all basic, basic light, sql*plus, tools,odbc,sdk...

Can you please let us know where you have installed Oracle client and what is your setting for Oracle home.

I unzipped to c:\oracle\instantclient_23_4 and ORACLE_HOME=C:\ORACLE\instantclient_23_4

as an alternative, simply download SQLcl, more features, easier to use, you only need Java https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/java/sqldeveloper/sqlcl-latest.zip

Thank you thatjeffsmith, it may be worth looking into as a replacement but I have quite a few scripts which use the existing sqlplus and sqlloader tools so I need to get them functional asap.

I have talked to others in my organization which use sqlplus and they do not have .msb files in their folder trees either. Is this an old error which means something else now?
In most of the other QA I saw the recommendation is to reinstall but the instructions for the instant client zips are just to unzip under the ORACLE_HOME folder so since I did not "install" I am confused as to the next steps.

There are no visible msb files with Instant Client - they are embedded. Your problem is that you set ORACLE_HOME. This should never be set with Instant Client, for reasons like the one you see. Just unzip, and set PATH.
If you already had a database installed, then you probably don't need Instant Client (unless you want some newer version).  If you have multiple copies of Oracle software installed on Windows, you need to be careful how you set the environment to make sure only the specific version needed for each application is used.
